# JavaScript append HTML in for-loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, append

in the following snippet I have a for-loop and want to append the HTML Code in each Iteration to use the list inside my ul-Tag.
If I replace the += with the = operator it works, but only for the last element obviously.
How can I append it correctly in the loop?

```
    var text = "the Text"
    var list
    for (var i = 1; i < split_respone.length; i+=2) {
      list += <li className="link-list-item">
            <a
            href={split_respone[i]}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            className="link-list-item-url">
            {split_respone[i+1]}</a>
            </li>
    }
    string = <ul className="link-list">{text}{list}</ul>;
  } 
  const message = self.createChatBotMessage(string);
});
}
```

Comment: You have to intiailize `list` to an empty string: `var list = "";`. You also need to put backticks around your template strings.

Comment: What are `});` and `}` doing at the end?

Comment: but now my list is a string and gets printed in my frontend. I need a HTML Object so it doesn't print the string but shows the list.

Comment: What you do with the resulting string is a different problem.

Comment: You should assign it to `.innerHTML` of a DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set "list" to an empty string for it to work. Additionally, because you are combining strings, you need to enclose the HTML with quotes. (You can also use ``)

```
    var text = "the Text"
    var list = "";
    for (var i = 1; i < split_respone.length; i+=2) {
      list += '<li className="link-list-item">
            <a
            href={split_respone[i]}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            className="link-list-item-url">
            {split_respone[i+1]}</a>
            </li>'
    }
    string = <ul className="link-list">{text}{list}</ul>;
  } 
  const message = self.createChatBotMessage(string);
});
```

Comment: but now my list is a string and gets printed in my frontend. I need a HTML Object so it doesn't print the string but shows the list.

Comment: @reBo137 Can you try using `` instead of ''?

Comment: I got the solution. I initialized my list as list = [] and changed the += operator to list.push(html_code without "" or '')